# New-AzSqlDatabaseInstanceFailoverGroup Cross Subscription Setup Fails

Tags: sql, azure, instance, managed, failover

I'm trying to setup a cross-subscription failover group. The MS docs article for this cmdlet, and specifically the PartnerSubscriptionId parameter at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/new-azsqldatabaseinstancefailovergroup?view=azps-2.7.0 says:

-PartnerSubscriptionId
The subscription id of the secondary Managed Instance of the Instance Failover Group. This parameter is only needed for cross-subscription setup

The help for this cmdlet says the same thing. However, when I try to create a new FoG using a cross-subscription setup, an error is thrown that says cross subscrption (sic) setup is not allowed.

Portal doesn't support it. REST API is throwing a vague 'resource not found' error. How exactly is a cross-subscription failover group supposed to be created?  Thank you

Comment: Is that you want to create a failover group between managed instances in different subscriptions?